# Spinnaker: How to bring custom boms into spinnaker pod to be able to deploy it with hal?

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I would like to provide a [custom BOM (Bill of Materials)](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/operator/custom-boms/) to spinnaker so that I can configure the repos according to my needs. I am new to k8s, helm and spinnaker and altought reading the docu there are some things not entirely clear how to do that...

### Problem

I do not have access to the gcs store nor do I have direct access to external repos. So I need to configure the `artifactSources` accordingly

According to [the docu](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/operator/custom-boms/) I guess I should provide a custom bom in a way that they be read from the filesystem - so inside the container `spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0`

### My steps

#### Prepare kubernetes cluster

I do the initial deployment with helm something like

```sh
helm install stable/spinnaker --name=spinnaker --namespace=spinnaker -f values.yml
```

After I connect to the `spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0` pod and run

```sh
$ kubectl.exe exec -it spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard-0 -n spinnaker bash
```

#### Deploy Spinnaker

According to the docu [here](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/operator/custom-boms/) and [here](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/deploy/) I would do do something like

```sh
$ hal config version edit --version local:1.11.6
$ hal deploy apply
```

Which fails obviously cause there is no local bom file

```sh
Problems in Global:
! ERROR Unable to retrieve the Spinnaker bill of materials for
  version "local:1.11.6": /home/spinnaker/.hal/.boms/bom/1.11.6.yml (No such file
  or directory)

- Failed to prep Spinnaker deployment
```

### Question: How to provide custom BOM?

According to the docu the boms are expected to be in a specific directory and structure `${HALCONFIG_DIR}/.boms/boms/${VERSION}.yml`

So how to I get my custom POM there? When I look at the [helm-chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/spinnaker/templates/statefulsets/halyard.yaml) I don't see (or understand) how I could do that e.g. via `additional-config-maps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way but it is manually done, working within the `spinnaker-spinnaker-halyard` container. I'm sure there is a better way...

I add a custom bom as `additionalConfigMap` to the `values.yml` file

```
...
  additionalConfigMaps:
    create: true
    data:
      # https://storage.googleapis.com/halconfig/bom
      bom_1.12.4.yml: |
        version: 1.12.4
        timestamp: '2019-03-01 08:06:24'
        services:
          echo:
            version: 2.3.1-20190214121429
            commit: 5db9d437ca7f2fa374dcada17f77bbbb2965bd67
          clouddriver:
            version: 4.3.4-20190301030607
            commit: b5539c47aad309e24428abb8f8303aff45323b43
          deck:
            version: 2.7.4-20190228030607
            commit: dccdd730886a6beb0388e3622581d8da1ed8edbb
          fiat:
            version: 1.3.2-20190128153726
            commit: daf21b24330a5f22866601559aa0f7ac99590274
          front50:
            version: 0.15.2-20190222161456
            commit: 3105e86b8c084ad6ad78507e3a5e5a427f290b99
          gate:
            version: 1.5.2-20190301030607
            commit: b238ab993ab25381ce907260879548ed74a4953f
          igor:
            version: 1.1.1-20190213190226
            commit: 63d06a5c5d55f07443dd60a81035b35cf96238e7
          kayenta:
            version: 0.6.1-20190221030610
            commit: 81d906bf8307143f40fe88f8554baa318de25ef1
          orca:
            version: 2.3.1-20190220030610
            commit: bad45e78566449117b678a3317552cf53d0dd14e
          rosco:
            version: 0.9.0-20190123170846
            commit: 42f81a2501de6d40676d47661579a6106b5c3e8a
          defaultArtifact: {}
          monitoring-third-party:
            version: 0.11.2-20190222030609
            commit: 232c84a8a87cecbc17f157dd180643a8b2e6067a
          monitoring-daemon:
            version: 0.11.2-20190222030609
            commit: 232c84a8a87cecbc17f157dd180643a8b2e6067a
        dependencies:
          redis:
            version: 2:2.8.4-2
          consul:
            version: 0.7.5
          vault:
            version: 0.7.0
        artifactSources:
          debianRepository: https://nexus.intra/repository/spinnaker-releases/
          dockerRegistry: nexus.intra:5000/spinnaker-marketplace
          googleImageProject: marketplace-spinnaker-release
          gitPrefix: https://scm.intra/scm/SPIN/repos
```

Then link the custom bom in the `halyard` container, configure the version and run the deployment

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.hal/.boms/bom
ln -s /opt/halyard/additionalConfigMaps/bom_1.12.4.yml ~/.hal/.boms/bom/1.12.4.yml
hal config version edit --version local:1.12.4
hal deploy apply
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for. should be in the official documentation.